# Use of the Sobel Filter for Image Gradient [MATLAB]

Tags: image-processing, matlab, filters, gradient

I am using the Sobel filter for an RGB image. I have found two different ways to do that and the results look a little different. What is the difference between these two methods?

Method 1

```
 sbl=fspecial('Sobel');
 sbl_red=imfilter(Image(:,:,1));
```

Method 2

```
 [magred,dirred]=imgradient(Image(:,:,1),'Sobel')
```

Is there an advantage over one of the two methods? I am trying to find a structure of the image that is parallel to the x axis.

Comment: Build your own filters. That is the only way to know what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you go through the documentation of [`fspecial()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html) you'd see it returns the following filter:

```
h = fspecial('sobel') returns a 3-by-3 filter h that emphasizes horizontal edges using the smoothing effect by approximating a vertical gradient. To emphasize vertical edges, transpose the filter h'.

[ 1  2  1 
  0  0  0 
 -1 -2 -1 ]
```

Namely in the way you applied it above you only got the vertical element of the gradient.

While `imgradient()` returns the image of the magnitude of the Gradient (Which has Vertical and Horizontal elements) and its direction.